# Not getting Current DropDownList value on HTTP Post in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC Application. I have used a `dropdownlist` to select value. Now, there is an update form in which there are multiple items that can be updated.

The problem is if I update the field and do not select an item from `dropdownlist`, its did not get the existing value and instead shows `Null`.

How is it possible to get the `exisiting selected value in dropdownlist in HTTPPost`?

View

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(Student => Student.Gender)
    @Html.DropDownList("Gender","Select Gender")
</div>
```

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                var studentToUpdate = (from students in db.Students
                                       where students.StudentId == student.StudentId
                                       select students).Single();

                studentToUpdate.Name = student.Name;
                studentToUpdate.Gender = student.Gender;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
        else
        {
            return View(student);
        }
    }
```

Thing is when I am updating name and gender then everything works fine. However, If I update only name then at the time of postback the value in dropdown box turns out to be null i.e. I need to select an item from dropdownlist.

Comment: plz post relevant code...

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the value also, not only the Text of Drop Down List.

```
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option selected="selected" value="saab">Saab</option>
```

When you assign the value you have to assign relevant value attribute for the drop down list option.

This is just a guess.